# Writing and sending a HTML-based Email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've seen all these emails that include pictures, divs, paragraphs and what-not inside an email.

How do I actually go about doing that?

Can anyone give me a rough explanation on how these things work? I am pasting my HTML code inside my email and it only shows text. Is there anything I should enable/disable?

(I know I will need a mailing list, but that's probably a different topic.)

Comment: I think it is depending on the client who renders it, if the client is able to render HTML, then it should not be a problem.

Comment: It's also displaying text to me, I think i'm missing something here.

Comment: Sometimes, due to security, html contents are blocked and the client shows warning, it also gives option to enable the html content. I saw this in Microsoft Outlook

Comment: That usually blocks everything except text. It's not blocking anything. Its showing <html>stuff</html> and all that stuff.

Comment: @RenoYeo If you're in PHP, check out [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: cool. will check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of the message should be formatted as [Multipart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) MIME (with the email header stating that it is formatted that way) with at least two parts: A text/html part and a text/plain part (for email clients that don't support HTML and to reduce the number of This Is A Spammer flags given the email).

Most graphical email clients will only allow HTML to be entered using their WYSIWYG tools. Custom HTML requires specialist software.

Comment: define : specialist software :( do you mean software like Dreamweaver?

Comment: @RenoYeo — No, specialist email software. I've never used anything off the shelf that did this, only libraries such as [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::MIME::CreateHTML).

Comment: whoa. wow. its that complicated? i was thinking of creating and senging HTML emails via PHP's mail() function.

Comment: Don't use `mail()`, there are libraries for PHP that can handle multipart MIME.

Comment: Right, multipart MIME... I think I'll go search around that keyword for a bit for PHP. Thanks for the tip!